# system command and search specific and show that

Tags: usb

lsusb -v gives verbose response of usb devices.

Example:

```
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 413c:2003 Dell Computer Corp. Keyboard
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               1.10
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0         8
  idVendor           0x413c Dell Computer Corp.
  idProduct          0x2003 Keyboard
  bcdDevice            3.06
  iManufacturer           1 
  iProduct                2 
  iSerial                 0 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           34
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xa0
      (Bus Powered)
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower               70mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Boot Interface Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 Keyboard
      iInterface              0 
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType        33
          bcdHID               1.10
          bCountryCode            0 Not supported
          bNumDescriptors         1
          bDescriptorType        34 Report
          wDescriptorLength      65
         Report Descriptors: 
           ** UNAVAILABLE **
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0008  1x 8 bytes
        bInterval              24
```

Now I want to see only `bInterfaceProtocol` of `Interface Descriptor` section for `Bus 003 Device 003` device only or I want to list that `bInterfaceProtocol` content of all usb devices.Can anyone tell me any specific format for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do it using `lsusb` only. You can:

1. Use the `-s` or the `-d` options to make [`lsusb`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/lsusb.8.html) show output for only specific devices:

   ```
   -s [[bus]:][devnum]
         Show only devices in specified bus and/or devnum.  Both ID's are
         given in decimal and may be omitted.

   -d [vendor]:[product]
         Show  only  devices  with  the  specified vendor and product ID.
         Both ID's are given in hexadecimal.
   ```
2. And use `grep` to filter out the fields.

For example:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0e0f:0002 VMware, Inc. Virtual USB Hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0e0f:0003 VMware, Inc. Virtual Mouse
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0e0f:0002 VMware, Inc. Virtual USB Hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
$ lsusb -s 003:003
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0e0f:0002 VMware, Inc. Virtual USB Hub
$ lsusb -s 003:003 -v | grep bInterfaceProtocol
  bInterfaceProtocol      0 Full speed (or root) hub
# lsusb -v | grep -e bInterfaceProtocol -e Bus
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 Full speed (or root) hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0e0f:0002 VMware, Inc. Virtual USB Hub
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 Full speed (or root) hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0e0f:0003 VMware, Inc. Virtual Mouse
      bInterfaceProtocol      2 Mouse
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0e0f:0002 VMware, Inc. Virtual USB Hub
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 Full speed (or root) hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 Full speed (or root) hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 Full speed (or root) hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 Full speed (or root) hub
```

Comment: That's a short precise exact to the point informative way of answering. Thanks for the help. Carry on helping :)]

Comment: Just wanted to know, if I want to filter out something, ie. I do not want to see items of which bInterfaceProtocol is 0
In that case how to filter that out?

Comment: @anupam_on well, you can use `grep` multiple times, but the expression becomes complex. Try: `lsusb -v | grep -e bInterfaceProtocol -e Bus | grep -B1 'bInterfaceProtocol *[^0]'`. The `[^0]` indicates any character except `0`.